# Що означає слово "шрайбати", і яке його походження?

Tags: етимологія, значення-слів, дієслова, діалекти

У одному розважальному відео [почув](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukonBMs0WM0&feature=youtu.be&t=181) слово "шрайбати". Воно вживається в багатьох місцях, зокрема, у реченні:

> шрайбати українські диктанти

Перше, що спадає на думку – це "писати".

Чи це так? Яке походження цього слова і георгафія вживання?

Бо я, наприклад, його вперше чую.

Comment: @bytebuster, навіть [так](//uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/schreiben).

Comment: @Sasha ба більше http://sum.in.ua/s/shkrjabaty (3. перех., перен., зневажл.)

Comment: @chizh, хм, ніколи б не подумав, що «шкрябати» споріднене зі «schreiben» — але, мабуть, Ви праві.

Comment: @Sasha за етимологію сказати нічого не можу, тут треба обережно, бо на "скрябати" ґуґл видає творчість фоменка, але звучання і зміст співпадають. можливо, це пізніший вплив германських мов на українську

Comment: @chizh, якраз у звучанні і змісті мені бачиться мало спільного. (чи я чогось не знаю, і німці раніше вимовляли його як «скр…»/«шкр…»?) я якраз думав, Ви про етимологію «шкрябати».

Comment: я з [цим словом](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schrijven) знайомий з іншої германської мови. походить від латинського [scribo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scribo#Latin) а те від *skreybʰ. [тут](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf#page=284) подано спільнокореневе походження від *skreybʰ для скребти. [тут](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom6.pdf#page=435) шкребти-шкрябати подається як спільнокорінне до скребти. да і посуті процес письма _від руки_ - це нашкрябання символів по поверхні

Answer (score 16, accepted):

«Шра́йбати» — очевидно з німецького *[schreiben](//uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/schreiben)* ⟨шра́йбен⟩ «писати». Дієвідмінюється так: *schreibe*, *schreibst*, *schreibt* — тобто основа *schreib-*, тому логічно, що українці *шрайб*ають, а не *шрайбен*яють/*шрайбен*ять/*шрайбен*ють.

Вживається, як мінімум, у Львові. Але точний регіон установити важко. Я припускаю, що в різних регіонах воно може мати й різний рівен вжитку (десь — місцеве широковживане слово, а десь — рідковживане арґо), і різні відтінки значення (десь — писати, а десь — саме абияк писати):

- [Олекса Горбач «Арґо українських школярів і студентів» (1966)](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Horbach_Oleksa/Argo_ukrainskykh_shkoliariv_i_studentiv/), ст. 204–206:

  > Понад 350 школярських арґотизмів 1930-их pp. із середніх шкіл *Львова* (Л), *Тернополя* (Т), *Дрогобича* (Д), *Станиславова-Іванофранківська* (С), *Коломиї* (К) й *Золочева* (3) зібрали ми в 1948—52 pp. на еміграції; львівські арґотизми полягають здебільша на наших власних поміченнях з тих років (філія Академічної гімназії у Львові), підтверджених відповідями дальших інформаторів; більшість цих арґотизмів у позавузькошколярських ділянках, як звичайно, тотожня з виразами вулично-злодійського арґо. Арґотизми інших осередків це деколи всього діялектні вульґаризми даного говіркового масиву. Крім позичень з польської мови та з польського школярського й вуличного арґо, зустрічається низка германізмів — залишки здебільша ранішого підавстрійського школярського побуту.
  >
  > <…> II <…> г) <…> *шрайбува́ти* **Л[ьвів, ]Д[рогобич, ]Т[ернопіль]**, *шра́йбати* (нім. schreiben «писати»), *шкрі́бати* «писати»; <…>, *нашкрі́бати* **Л[ьвів, ]Т[ернопіль]** «написати (багато)»; <…>, *відшрайбува́ти* **Л[ьвів]** «відписати (завдання)»; <…>.
- [Наталя Хобзей, Ксеня Сімович, Тетяна Ястремська, Ганна Дидик-Меуш «Лексикон **львівський**: поважно і на жарт» (2009)](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Khobzei_Natalia/Leksykon_lvivskyi_povazhno_i_na_zhart/), анотація і ст. 127, 348–385, 630, 639:

  > Фіксація особливостей мовлення **Львова** XX століття — мета цієї праці. Джерелами стали насамперед власні спостереження авторок за словниковим фондом мовців рідного міста, а також художня та мемуарна література авторів-львів’ян.
  >
  > - *відшрайбува́ти* шк[ільне] переписати; списати (завдання, вправу тощо) (ст)  | → *відвалити*
  > - *нашкра́бати (нашкрібати)* 1. пошкрябати (поверхню) (ср, ст) 2. неакуратно, недбало написати (м, ср, ст)
  > - *нашкрі́бати* → *нашкра́бати*
  > - *нашра́йбати* шк[ільне] недбало написати (завдання, вправу тощо) (ст, ср, м)
  > - *шкрі́бати (шкря́бати)* писати (перев. недбало) (м, ср, ст) | *шра́йбати*
  > - *шкря́бати* → *шкрібати* (м, ср, ст)
  > - *шра́йбати* недбало, неохайно писати (м, ср, ст) | *шкрі́бати (шкря́бати)*

  <sup>Позначки: «м», «ср», «ст» — «молодше покоління», «середнє покоління», «старше покоління».</sup>
- [Журнал «Вісник Прикарпатською університету. Філологія» (2009, Івано-Франківськ, випуск XXI–XXII)](http://lib.pu.if.ua/files/Visniki/fililogija/748305%20%D0%92%D0%9F%D0%A3%20%D0%A4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F%20(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE).,%20%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BF.%2021%20-%2022.,%202009%20%D1%80..pdf), ст. 47:

  > Гуцульські лексичні діалектизми німецького та польського походження притаманні не тільки **гуцульським** говіркам, а й **іншим** говорам **південно-західного наріччя (покутсько-буковинським, бойківським)**, тому відносимо їх до функціонально-гуцульських. Серед гуцульських лексичних діалектизмів німецького походження виявлено <…> *шрайбати* // *шрайбувати* *зневажл.* “писати” *пор. нім.* schréiben <…>.
- [Дмитро Савчук «Словник українських говірок **карпатського** регіону: пояснення та походження слів» (2012, Київ — Косів, «Писаний Камінь», ISBN 978-966-8519-70-3), ст. 102](http://evrika.if.ua/93/):

  > Шрайбати — писати (німецьке schreiben — писати)
- [Телеканал ZIK: Говірник: Шрайбати](http://zik.ua/tv/video/30355):

  > **Галицько-львівський** діалект… *[Шра́йбати](//youtu.be/2w6cH0lD-Fk?t=28s)*. Означає «писати»… З німецької мови. Часто застосовують з негативним відтінком, тобто писати абияк і негарним почерком. «Шрайбає, як курка лабою.»
- [«Гуцульський словник (найвживаніша лексика)» на сайті турагенції](http://www.karpaty365.com/category/228/ukr) (неавторитетне):

  > У таблиці наведені слова як **гуцульської** говірки, так і **інших** діалектів, що поширені **у Карпатах або у всій західній Україні**.
  >
  > шрайбати | писати
- [«Словник **закарпатських** слів» Микуляка Жені](http://words.eugene-home.kiev.ua/index.php?char=%D0%A8&page=5) (заповнюється користувачами):

  > Шрайбати | Некрасиво писати, перекреслювати написане
- [Юрій Балега «Політичне русинство і будівництво Української Держави» (2003, Ужгород, «Гражда», ISBN 966711256X)](//books.google.com/books?id=CjUiAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22) — чи то наводячи русинську цитату, чи то пишучи русинською, чи то пародіюючи **русинську** (контексту не видно):

  > Исправляя хыбу и в знак уваженія к нему я вушмарив за облок фединишинцьово правописаніє и впредь буду шрайбати лем по-петровайськы.

І, як не дивно:

- [В. С. Єлістратов «Словник **російського** арґо: матеріали 1980–1990 рр.» (2002)](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_16649):

  > ШРА́ЙБИТЬ, -блю, -бишь; *несов.*, *что* и *без доп.* Писать. Все мемуары шрайбят.
  >    От нем. schreiben в том же зн.

Answer (score 1):

Мені слово "шрайбати" вперше трапилося в книзі Остапа Вишні "Берлінський день", де є такі речення: "Добре, як би було можна про Берлін так шайб-шрайб і вже вам про весь Берлін нашрайбав. Нашрайбаєш лихої години, коли самого населення, кажуть, тут чотири з половиною мільйони". З тутешнього коментаря довідався, що слово має німецьке походження. Вишня використав його у іронічному аспекті, через схожість із українським "шкрябати".